# High Memory Usage - Unity profiler shows that a single font texture takes up more than 150 MB of memory on android device

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, fonts, textures

While trying to optimize a Unity game I discovered that font textures take up a ridiculous amount of memory on mobile devices (tested on Android - OnePlus 6). The texture does not seem to be cleared between scene switches, unlike the Editor, where the maximum size of a font texture is 4 MB at all times (even in the same scene with loads of different text elements) and does not climb any higher. Meanwhile, opening new scenes/windows with different texts increases the font texture memory even more and more on my phone. The attached image shows the profiler snippet when profiling my OnePlus 6 phone, after navigating to multiple scenes and opening different panels with various texts (which were using the same font).

My question is: what can I do about it - is it a bug or a feature? Why is the allocated texture memory not cleared/reset as it is on the Editor?

[image: High Memory Usage Font Texture Unity]

Comment: What action is causing the texture size to grow on the device ? 
It is a scene loading ? A GameObject being destroy/created ? Are you using UnityEngine.UI set or TextMesh ?

Comment: From what I can gather it is the creation/enabling of objects that reference the same Font Asset. This can also occur because of loading a new scene where the font is being used. The font is mainly used on UnityEngine.UI elements, but there is a TextMeshPro font generated from it as well (although TMPro doesn't seem to be the culprit here).

Comment: Did you find a fix for this or a explanation as to why this happens? I am facing the same issue leading to an out of memory crash of the app.

Comment: did you ever solve this?